# Is $B=([0,\frac{1}{2}]\times \{b\})\cup ((\frac{1}{2},1]\times \{a\})$ compact?

Tags: general-topology

Let $(\mathbb{R},\textrm{usual})$ and $(Y:=\{a,b\},\textrm{trivial})$ be two topology spaces. Now let $X=\mathbb{R}\times Y$ equipped with the product topology. Consider the subsets $A=[0,1]\times \{a\}$ and $B=([0,\frac{1}{2}]\times \{b\})\cup ((\frac{1}{2},1]\times \{a\})$.

$A$ is clearly compact, but I am not sure if $B$ is also compact, since it contains $(\frac{1}{2},1]$ that is not compact in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: can you be more specific about the topology on $Y$?

Comment: Specifically, we were not sure whether trivial means discrete or indiscrete.

Comment: @ForeverMozart Sorry, I always thought "trivial topology" is a synonym of "indiscrete topology".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the map $f : [0,1] \to X$ given by
$$ f(x) = \begin{cases}
   (x,b),&\quad\text{if $x \leq \tfrac{1}{2}$};\\[1ex]
   (x,a),&\quad\text{if $x > \tfrac{1}{2}$}.
\end{cases} $$
Then $f$ is a continuous function with image $B$. (One way to check this: verify that $\pi_1 \circ f$ and $\pi_2 \circ f$ are continuous, where $\pi_1 : X \to \mathbb{R}$ and $\pi_2 : X \to Y$ are the coordinate projections.) Since $[0,1]$ is compact, the image of $f$ is also compact, which is $B$.

Comment: Ah, but the singletons $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ are neither open nor closed in $Y$, so this doesn't matter.

Comment: Right. Thanks. Should have read the comments more carefully.